# TypeError: axios(...).then is not a function

Tags: javascript, axios

I am creating a javascript function to use in glideapps, following this [process](https://docs.glideapps.com/all/reference/data-editor/computed-columns/experimental-code-column#making-changes-to-your-code). The function takes in a google maps api url as a string input, and returns the json file as a string output. Using the example from [google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-text#maps_http_places_textsearch_incomplete_address-js), I created this test which works fine.

```
function test(request_url){
  var axios = require('axios');
  var config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: request_url,
    headers: { }
  };

  var final = axios(config)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
  return final}
```

When I use the same function in the code for the glideapp function, I get two errors. First, I got the error: `Error: Module name "axios" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])` and addressed it by using   `var axios = require(['foo'], function (foo)` instead.

```
window.function=function(request_url){ 
  var axios = require(['axios'], function (axios) {
    //axios is now loaded.
  });
  var config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: request_url,
    headers: { }
  };

  var final = axios(config)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
  return final}
```

Now I get the error `TypeError: axios(...).then is not a function`. How do I fix this? Thank you

Comment: Did you install `axios` first? Something like `npm install axios` and then did you import it before calling it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the axios variable inside the function of require instead of the returning value of require function.

```
require(['axios'], function (axios) {
    window.function=function(request_url){ 
      var config = {
        method: 'get',
        url: request_url,
        headers: { }
      };

      var final = axios(config)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
      return final
    }
});
```

Comment: This is giving me a script error: window.function is not a function